# how can i use optimization toolbox(matlab) in a right way?

Tags: matlab, optimization

my code：

```
q0 = [10,20];
qv0 = [0,0];
qa0 = [0,0];
qf = [60,100];
qvf = [0,0];
qaf = [0,0];

%syms tf;% 没有解析解
tf = optimvar('tf');
prob = optimproblem;
prob.Objective = tf;
x.tf=0;

nn = length(q0);
for i=1:nn
      a0(i) = q0(i);                                       
      a1(i) = qv0(i);
      a2(i) = qa0(i)/2.0;
      a3(i) = (20*(qf(i) - q0(i)) - (8*qvf(i) + 12*qv0(i))*tf + (qaf(i) - 3*qa0(i))*tf^2)/(2*tf^3);
      a4(i) = (-30*(qf(i) - q0(i)) + (14*qvf(i) + 16*qv0(i))*tf - (2*qaf(i) - 3*qa0(i))*tf^2)/(2*tf^4);
      a5(i) = (12*(qf(i) - q0(i)) - (60*qvf(i) + 6*qv0(i))*tf + (qaf(i) - qa0(i))*tf^2)/(2*tf^5);
end

for j=1:nn     
    prob.Constraints.cons1 =  a1(j) + 2*a2(j)*tf + 3*a3(j)*tf^2 + 4*a4(j)*tf^3 + 5*a5(j)*tf^4 <= 5;
    prob.Constraints.cons2 =  2*a2(j) + 6*a3(j)*tf + 12*a4(j)*tf^2 + 20*a5(j)*tf^3 <= 0.5;
    sol = solve(prob,x) end
```

Content of the error report：

```
Solving problem using fmincon.

错误使用 optim.problemdef.OptimizationProblem/solve

Nonlinear constraint function is undefined at initial point. Fmincon cannot continue.

出错 main (第 28 行)

    sol = solve(prob,x)
```

Problem Background.

I know the starting angle, the velocity, the acceleration, and I want to use a fifth polynomial planning to find the time under the constraints using the optimizatiom toolbox.

Comment: Change this line: `prob.Objective = tf;`. `prob.Objective` should be your objective function of the variable `tf`.

Comment: What do `q0`, `qv0`, … mean? What are `a0` to `a5`? What is `tf`? What is `nn`? Please clarify your problem.